# Unicorn not reading ENV variables

Tags: bash, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I'm having some issues with `SECRET_KEY_BASE` setting on our production Ubuntu server with Unicorn and nginx. I added the variable to `.bashrc` and its reading fine when I try `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`, but for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
app error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
```

Also, when I try to access the variable with `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` from within the console in production environment, I can read it fine.

I tried restarting Unicorn and server and it doesn't help. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the variables to the `unicorn.conf` file, since it seems you are launching Unicorn with a different user or without sourcing your `.bashrc`.

In any case, I suggest you use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem to store your env variables in a `.env` file within your project. That is the cleanest way I know. If you need to have `capistrano` integration and handle all the different environments with ease, you can also use [dotenv-deployment](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv-deployment#multiple-environments) gem.

Comment: But isn't dotenv recommended only for test and development environment?

Comment: Have a look at dotenv-deployment gem